@SerializedName in apex to handle reserved variable is not working , what is the best way to go about
Why does @SerializedName('from') not working in apex salesforce
global class WhatsappResponseWebhook {
    
    @HttpGet
    global static Integer validationReq(){
        system.debug('inside==>');
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        String mode=req.params.get('hub.mode');
        Integer challenge=Integer.valueof(req.params.get('hub.challenge'));
        String token=req.params.get('hub.verify_token');
        return challenge;
    }
    
    
    @HttpPost
    global static void postMessage() {
        try {
            system.debug('Inside postMessage');
            
            // Parse the incoming JSON payload
            String data = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
            system.debug('data ==> ' + data);
            
            Map<String, Object> wad = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(data);
            system.debug('wad ==> ' + wad);
            
            List<Object> entryList = (List<Object>) wad.get('entry');
            Map<String, Object> entry = (Map<String, Object>) entryList[0];
            List<Object> changesList = (List<Object>) entry.get('changes');
            Map<String, Object> changes = (Map<String, Object>) changesList[0];
            Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) changes.get('value');
            List<Object> contactsList = (List<Object>) value.get('contacts');
            Map<String, Object> contacts = (Map<String, Object>) contactsList[0];
            List<Object> messagesList = (List<Object>) value.get('messages');
            
            Map<String, Object> messages = (Map<String, Object>) messagesList[0];
            system.debug('messages ==> ' + (messagesList));
            system.debug('messages ==> ' + (messages));
            system.debug('changes ==> ' + (String) changes.get('field'));
            List<Message__c> messageRecords = new List<Message__c>();
            
            for (Object msg : messagesList) {
                String messageJson = JSON.serialize(msg);
                MessageWrapper message = (MessageWrapper) JSON.deserialize(messageJson, MessageWrapper.class);
                
                Message__c newMessage = new Message__c();
                newMessage.RAW_Data__c = messageJson;
                newMessage.Type__c = 'Inbound';
                newMessage.Message__c = message.text.body;
                newMessage.Phone__c =   message.phone;
                system.debug( '++'+message.phone);
                messageRecords.add(newMessage);
            }
            
            if (!messageRecords.isEmpty()) {
                insert messageRecords;
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug('Error in postMessage: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    // Wrapper class for message parsing
    public class MessageWrapper {
        @SerializedName('from')
        public String phone;
        public String id;
        public TextBody text;
        public Long timestamp;
        public String type;
    }
    
    public class TextBody {
        public String body;
    } 
    
}```


Issue:
@SerializedName annotation not working in apex code because salesforce does not support this annotation, as it is specific to Gson library and not apex.
Probable solution:
Try below, fyi i haven't tested it out:
global class WhatsappResponseWebhook {


@HttpGet
global static Integer validationReq(){
    system.debug('inside==>');
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    String mode=req.params.get('hub.mode');
    Integer challenge=Integer.valueof(req.params.get('hub.challenge'));
    String token=req.params.get('hub.verify_token');
    return challenge;
}


@HttpPost
global static void postMessage() {
    try {
        system.debug('Inside postMessage');
        
        // Parse the incoming JSON payload
        String data = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
        system.debug('data ==> ' + data);
        
        Map<String, Object> wad = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(data);
        system.debug('wad ==> ' + wad);
        
        List<Object> entryList = (List<Object>) wad.get('entry');
        Map<String, Object> entry = (Map<String, Object>) entryList[0];
        List<Object> changesList = (List<Object>) entry.get('changes');
        Map<String, Object> changes = (Map<String, Object>) changesList[0];
        Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) changes.get('value');
        List<Object> contactsList = (List<Object>) value.get('contacts');
        Map<String, Object> contacts = (Map<String, Object>) contactsList[0];
        List<Object> messagesList = (List<Object>) value.get('messages');
        
        Map<String, Object> messages = (Map<String, Object>) messagesList[0];
        system.debug('messages ==> ' + (messagesList));
        system.debug('messages ==> ' + (messages));
        system.debug('changes ==> ' + (String) changes.get('field'));
        List<Message__c> messageRecords = new List<Message__c>();
        
        for (Object msg : messagesList) {
            String messageJson = JSON.serialize(msg);
            MessageWrapper message = (MessageWrapper) JSON.deserialize(messageJson, MessageWrapper.class);
            
            Message__c newMessage = new Message__c();
            newMessage.RAW_Data__c = messageJson;
            newMessage.Type__c = 'Inbound';
            newMessage.Message__c = message.text.body;
            newMessage.Phone__c =   message.fromPhone;  // i would suggest to update this from previous one, you might run into reserve keywords
            system.debug( '++'+message.fromPhone);
            messageRecords.add(newMessage);
        }
        
        if (!messageRecords.isEmpty()) {
            insert messageRecords;
        }
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        system.debug('Error in postMessage: ' + e.getMessage());
    }
}

// Wrapper class for message parsing
public class MessageWrapper {
    public String fromPhone;  // i would suggest to update this from previous one, you might run into reserve keywords
    public String id;
    public TextBody text;
    public Long timestamp;
    public String type;
}

public class TextBody {
    public String body;
} 

}
